# Using .Split to remove empty entries

Tags: vb.net, split

I am trying to split at every space " ", but it will not let me remove empty entries and then find the length, but it is treated as a syntax error.

My code:

```
TextBox1.Text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Too long for me to copy and paste in here, something about treating as a character

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, the first parameter to the `Split` function needs to be an array of strings or characters.  Try:

```
TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

You might not have noticed this before when you didn't specify the 2nd parameter.  This is because the `Split` method has an overload which takes in a ParamArray.  This means that calls to `Split("string 1", "string 2", "etc")` auto-magically get converted into a call to `Split(New String() {"string 1", "string 2", "etc"})`

Comment: Doesn't compile when strict is on.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
TextBox1.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

```
TextBox1.Text = "1 2 3  5 6"
TextBox1.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

Result: Length = 5

Answer (score 1):

```
// char array is used instead of normal char because ".Split()"
// accepts a char array
char[] c = new char[1];
//space character in array
c[0] = ' ';
// a new string array is created which will hold whole one line
string[] Warray = Line.Split(c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```